# Is it possible to see the date/time for a Google Drive folder for the most recent add/modify/delete time/date of something within it?

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to see the date/time of the item that was most recently changed within a Google Drive folder, without having to find that item within the folder first?

When browsing Google Drive in a web browser, it shows last modified for the *folder itself*, *not* the contents *within it*. For example in my drive, I see that a folder was last modified on 24 December, but one of the files *within* the folder was last modified on 2 January.

What I would like to see is a date/time associated with the folder that is for the most recent date/time when *any* of its contents were changed, added to or removed. In the above example this date would be 2 January. And if I deleted another file on January 8, then the folder that contained it would report January 8 as being the last modification date (even though the file deleted is no longer there, perhaps the date could have the summary of the last change). For my need, the folder would have to report such modify/add/delete changes to anything within it (recursively - i.e. within subfolders of subfolders etc.)

Comment: The last modified date for folders only show addition, removal and renames of files within the folder, not the respective file contents. This is also true within Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to find the time for **items** in the past, found it by clicking the (i) for details, then clicking the activity tab. On the date that's shown hover over and the time is displayed!

[image]

Answer (score -2):

On the left pane, click *More* → *Activity*.

That will sort all documents by time even if in a folder.

Comment: fyi - i got that tidbit from this thread    http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/m71BEN9-wtQ

Comment: Looks like this has been renamed to  Recent